# UITableView footer animation issue

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an accordion style table in my app - when user clicks a cell it expands when she clicks it again it collapses. This table also has a footer. To animate the expand/collapse, I use `[tableView beginUpdates]` and `[tableView endUpdates]` (between those blocks I change the table height). Everything works fine when the cell is expanded, but when the cell is collapsed the footer animation looks weird (cell animates nicely). It's kind of hard to explain but it is almost like it disappears for a moment and then appears again. Has anyone had this problem or does anyone know what's causing this?

Comment: Which animation pattern have you used ? can you post sample code as well ?

Comment: @parilogic I'm not using any animation patterns specifically, [beginUpdates] and [endUpdates] takes care of the animation work. Basically the code looks like this: `[tableView beginUpdates]; tableView.heightconstraint.constant = cellsExpanded + CellsCollapsed; [tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: I'm facing this issue now...did you ever find a fix for it?

Comment: i am facing with this issue too. Anybody has solved it?

Comment: @user1898712, did u solve it?

Comment: @flouwer, or you?)